# Low beams is not working

Tags: honda

I have a 2012 Honda accord coupe Low beams are not  working However, my high beams are working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From what I can see, it looks like your low beams are separate bulbs. Can you verify that? If they are separate lights, then likely they are burned out and/or the fuse needs replacing and/or the relay. All are fairly simple fixes.

Comment: If  bulbs, fuses and relays are all ok, another thing that I run into commonly for lights is internal failure of the controlling electronic module.